# NSUserDefaults not loading the numbers I want it to

Tags: xcode, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to use NSUserDefaults to save two variables after app shutdown. One being firstBoot and the other showAgain. Prepare for bad code-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; //Here is where it is supposed to be loading the firstBoot variable to check whether or not it is the first boot
    NSInteger boot = [defaults1 integerForKey:@"firstBoot"];
    firstBoot = boot; //Sort of pointless variable swapping

    if (firstBoot == 0) //Detects if isn't first boot, checks whether or not showAgain is yes or no (1=yes, 0=no)
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSInteger boot = [defaults1 integerForKey:@"firstBoot"];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSInteger show = [defaults2 integerForKey:@"showAgain"];
        firstBoot = boot; //More var swapping
        showAgain = show; //^^
    }
    else
    {
        firstBoot = 1; //If it is the first boot, or the variable wasn't 0, it sets them both to 1.
        showAgain = 1;
    }
    if ((firstBoot == 1) || (showAgain == 1)) //Checks if its the firstBoot or showAgain is set to yes
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Check the 'About' tab for help!" //Displays alert
                                                message:@""
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Don't show again"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"firstboot and showagain != 1" //Displays alert if it isn't the first boot, or isn't 1 and showAgain isn't set to yes(1).
                                                    message:@""
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"wrong"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Alert-

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) 
    {
        showAgain = 0; //If user clicks "Don't show again", set showAgain to off(0) and tell it it isn't the first boot anymore
        firstBoot = 0;

        NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults1 setInteger:0 forKey:@"firstBoot"]; //Hopefully stores firstBoot as 0
        [defaults1 synchronize];

        NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults2 setInteger:0 forKey:@"showAgain"]; //Again storing showAgain as 0
        [defaults2 synchronize];
    }
}
```

The first alert should pop up the very first time you run the app, while the second one is a debugger placeholder, and should run every time after the first time. For me, the second one is running first, telling me that firstBoot and showAgain != 1.

Comment: You could store BOOLs in your defaults rather than numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSInteger boot = [defaults1 integerForKey:@"firstBoot"];` will return 0 until you have saved a value in your defaults. `0`, `NO` or `nil` are returned for keys that don't have any values stored.

The correct way to handle this is to register default values before you try to retrieve these user defaults.

```
// register default values. until you save your own value "firstBoot" will return YES
// you should put these two lines in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`
// method of the AppDelegate. Add all userdefaults that should have default values there
NSDictionary *defaultUserDefaults = @{ @"firstBoot" : @YES };
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultUserDefaults];

// use BOOL instead of integer
BOOL firstBoot = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstBoot"];
if (firstBoot) {
    NSLog(@"first launch");
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"firstBoot"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; 
}
else {
    NSLog(@"has been launched before");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How would firstBoot be set to YES on the first boot? Who would have set it?

Call registerDefaults: at the start of the application for all properties that should have values different from 0 before they have been explicitely set. For example, with a key firstBoot = YES. Alternatively, use a property "notFirstBoot" where the return value for missing properties ("NO") is what you actually want.

And there is really no need to call standardUserDefaults again and again.